# system.web doesnt contain definition for script

Tags: asp.net-ajax

The type or namespace name 'Script' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

it gives error in the following line
"System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService"

i have included name space of system.web

Answer (score 10):

Two problems:

1. The class `System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptServiceAttribute` exists in the `System.Web.Extensions` assembly, not `System.Web`.  Make sure you're referencing the `System.Web.Extensions` assembly in your project.
2. When referencing an attribute explicitly, you'll need to provide its full name of "ScriptServiceAttribute", and not just "ScriptService".

Once I referenced System.Web.Extensions, the following compiled for me:

```
System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptServiceAttribute ss;
```

Comment: The type or namespace name 'Extensions' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) 

was that what u were reffering to  michael?

Comment: i dont know why i intellisense doesnt show extensions when i write system.web.

Comment: @Jaspal - looks like Andrey answered your questions.

Answer (score 5):

Google is your best friend. MSDN second.

> ScriptServiceAttribute Class
>
> Namespace:  System.Web.Script.Services
>
> Assembly:  System.Web.Extensions (in
>   **System.Web.Extensions.dll**)

did you add reference to this dll?

Comment: i think i m missing something very basic... as i m   new to programming

Comment: namespace can span across multiple dll files. you will see Script in in System.Web if you add reference to System.Web.Extensions.dll. If you are very new to programming may be you should start from the beginning, not from advanced tasks? if you want to study .net you should read some books first so this stuff with namespaces and dll is not a mystery for you.

Comment: thanks a lot... i got ur point friends..
adding a reference is done by right clicking on project :p
cheers

Answer (score 1):

look into C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET 2.0 AJAX Extensions\v1.0.61025\
and see if you find System.Web.Extensions.dll or the path
if you don't have the dll you can Download and install the ASP.NET AJAX 1.0 from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=883

Answer (score 1):

Add **targetFramework** to you web.config file.

```
<compilation debug="false" strict="false" explicit="true" **targetFramework="4.0"** />
```

It usually happens when you migrate codes particularly web methods from an older version, say .net 3.5 to a newer version.

Arun